# Networking with Python: No response from IP Phone

Tags: cisco, python, tcp, scapy

I'm an Automation Developer and lately I've taken it upon myself to control an IP Phone on my desk (Cisco 7940).

I have a third party application that can control the IP phone with SCCP (Skinny) packets. Through Wireshark, I see that the application will send 4 unique SCCP packets and then receives a TCP ACK message.

SCCP is not very well known, but it looks like this:

Ethernet( IP( TCP( SCCP( ))))

Using a Python packet builder: Scapy, I've been able to send the same 4 packets to the IP Phone, however I never get the ACK. In my packets, I have correctly set the sequence, port and acknowledge values in the TCP header. The ID field in the IP header is also correct.

The only thing I can imagine wrong is that it takes Python a little more than a full second to send the four packets. Whereas the application takes significantly less time. I've tried raising the priority for the Python shell with no luck.

Does anyone have an idea why I may not be receiving the ACK back?

Comment: If you use scapy directly from the shell, not from within python, does it work?

Comment: Nad i guess you could actually send packet with socket or socketserver, but build the packet with scapy.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. Do you also suspect the latency in sending the packets then?

Comment: Yeah, most likely. Try away, and let us know.

Comment: It's difficult to send the packets through the shell because my Python script determines the necessary ID, Sequence and Acknowledgement values for each packet. To enter in manually would be slower.

Comment: Yeah, i know you could pipe the input somehow with proper word splitting or something, not sure. Did not use scapy in awhile.

Comment: Have a dig about in the source code for Freeswitch.  See if you can decipher the magic runes in there for controlling phones with SCCP

Comment: @TomO'Connor Thank you for your insight; do you feel as though this is a more viable option than my Scapy+Python setup? If so, in what way?

Comment: I have no idea off the top of my head how SCCP works, but a neat idea I find is to have a rummage through something that already does it.  Freeswitch is pleasantly written, so worth a look.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code that we could look at.

Answer (score 1):

This website may be helpful in debugging why on your machine you aren't seeing the traffic you expect, and taking steps to modify your environment to produce the desired output.

> Normally, the Linux kernel takes care of setting up and sending and
> receiving network traffic. It automatically sets appropriate header
> values and even knows how to complete a TCP 3 way handshake. Uising
> the kernel services in this way is using a "cooked" socket.
>
> Scapy does not use these kernel services. It creates a "raw" socket. The
> entire TCP/IP stack of the OS is circumvented. Because of this, Scapy
> give us compete control over the traffic. Traffic to and from Scapy
> will not be filtered by iptables. Also, we will have to take care of
> the TCP 3 way handshake ourselves.

http://www.packetlevel.ch/html/scapy/scapy3way.html